# Find Project by Permalink, 404 if not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-status-code-404

I changed my show controller to find records by their permalink rather than their id (for SEO juiciness).

```
def show
  @project = Project.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
end
```

But, if I type in localhost:3000/projects/foo (and there is not a project with a foo permalink) I get a 500 server error instead of a 404 not found.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the specific error message that you get in the Rails console (or development.log)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be a 2.3 addition, but you can just use an exclaimation point after a dynamic finder like this:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find_by_permalink!(params[:id])
end
```

If nothing is found a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

I assume are getting a 500 error because your show action is trying to reference attributes of `@project` when the find is returning `nil`

You need to check to make sure `@projects` has some data and render a 404 by hand otherwise. On my site I render a custom action called 'error' in a similar situation:

```
render :action => 'error', :status => 404 if @projects.blank?
```

If `@projects` exists, then the show action renders as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can raise a 404 exception.